# Issue updating both pivot table and linked table it is based on

Tags: excel

I have a table that is linked to an Access database that is frequently being updated. The table is used to populate a pivot table.

I have the following macro that is executed when pressing a refresh button. The issue is when selecting this button the linked table is refreshed but for the pivot table to be refreshed I have to press the button again after the linked table is done refreshing with new data.

Should I wait until the linked table is refreshed using VBA and have pivot table refresh afterward? How can this be done:

**Current macro:**

```
Sub RefreshFunc()

ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll

End Sub
```

Comment: It's likely that the pivot table is refreshed before the linked table. If you need to refresh in a specific order, either do it one by one or refresh the pivot table second time separately after `RefreshAll`.

Comment: The double refresh 'feature' is well known and all over the internet.  First press refreshes the query and related table.  Second press refreshes the pivot table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
Sub ChangeConnectionRefreshModeAndRefreshAll()

'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Purpose:   Turn off background refreshing for all workbook connections.
'            This prevents hangs and crashes.  Cycle 2x
'
' Source:    https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/excel-forum/vba-macros/pause-macro-until-power-queries-finished-refreshing
'
' Revisions
' 01/30/19
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Dim Connection As WorkbookConnection
    Dim bugfix As Integer

        For bugfix = 1 To 2

            On Error Resume Next

            For Each Connection In ActiveWorkbook.Connections

                With Connection

                    If (.Type = xlConnectionTypeODBC) Then
                        .ODBCConnection.BackgroundQuery = False

                    Else

                        If (.Type = xlConnectionTypeOLEDB) Then
                            .OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery = False

                        End If

                    End If

                End With

            Connection.Refresh

            Next Connection

        Next bugfix

End Sub
```